# Can not remote Run QT Camera Example on i.Mx6Q

Tags: qt, qt-creator, embedded-linux, imx6

This is the application output, when I run app:

```
sh: /root/camera: not found
Application finished with exit code 127.
```

How to fix this problem? Thanks

### Environment

I'm using Buildroot 'imx6-sabresd_qt5_defconfig' and adding 'openssh', 'gdb'

And the following is what I set up Qt Creator for i.Mx6Q:

Tools > Options > Build & Run > Compilers
Name : imx6 buildroot GCC
buildroot/output/host/usr/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-g++

Tools > Options > Build & Run > Debuggers
Name : IMX6 buildroot gdb
buildroot/output/host/usr/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-gdb

Tools > Options > Build & Run > Qt Versions
Version Name : Qt %{Qt:Version} (buildroot)
buildroot/output/host/usr/bin/qmake

camera.pro

```
+ target.path = /root
+ INSTALLS += target
- target.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES]/multimediawidgets/camera
- INSTALLS += target
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally, I run on VMware Ubuntu.
When I not using VMware, the qt app remote run and debugging successfully.
Didn't change any environment setting.